# Filter nested dictionary based on number of elements in list

Tags: python, dictionary

How do i filter the following dictionary based on the condition that the ID has to contain three or more timestamps?

```
dict={10009: {196962305: [Timestamp('2019-12-27 03:06:50')]},
 10051: {2854032: [Timestamp('2019-12-27 19:16:11')],
  48600461: [Timestamp('2019-12-29 01:56:19')]},
 10061: {62464559: [Timestamp('2019-12-31 02:58:48'), Timestamp('2019-12-30 21:35:15'), Timestamp('2019-12-28 09:27:55'), [Timestamp('2019-12-28 12:05:32')]}}
```

Desired output:

```
new_dict={10061: {62464559: [Timestamp('2019-12-31 02:58:48'), Timestamp('2019-12-30 21:35:15'), Timestamp('2019-12-28 09:27:55'), [Timestamp('2019-12-28 12:05:32')]}}
```

Comment: there is error in your dictionary . in that output , i can see that one `]` is missing .

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What have you tried?

Comment: does the inner dictionary always have one key?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> It will work if the inner dictionary has only one key

```
res = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(list(v.values())[0]) > 2}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{10061: {62464559: [Timestamp('2019-12-31 02:58:48'), Timestamp('2019-12-30 21:35:15'), Timestamp('2019-12-28 09:27:55'), [Timestamp('2019-12-28 12:05:32')]]}}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Your code has produced the desired output